# SpringApplication class not found

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I used Maven to add spring-boot artifacts as dependencies.

```
SpringApplication class not found in spring-boot-starter-actuator version 1.5.8.RELEASE.
```

Has it been moved?

**POM Snippet**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

After using version 1.5.7.RELEASE, I had no issue finding the class.

**Code**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Add more tags so that you will get answer faster as everyone is able to see it. 2. Need to mention what are the steps to tried to solved the issue or how to you get this problem.

Comment: Would you kindly show your code that calls `SpringApplication` and the package you imported? Because it has not been removed.

Comment: I tried re-importing version 1.5.8.RELEASE today and it was able to download `spring-boot` jar from Maven Repository.

Answer (score 0):

The class `org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication` lives in the `spring-boot` jar not in the `spring-boot-starter-actuator`, the *-starter-* JARs are just wrapped POMs presenting a set of curated dependencies so the`spring-boot-starter-actuator` jar never contained `SpringApplication`.

You can get the spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar [from Maven Central](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.5.8.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar) and it definitely contains `org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication`.

Comment: You're correct, `SpringApplication` is part of `spring-boot`.

When using version 1.5.7.RELEASE, it did seem to locate the `spring-boot` jar in the `.m2` folder. But for the latest version, the jar did not get downloaded from the Maven Repository.